# Android Mediaplayer stops playing the button click sound after i click the button multiple times

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am using Mediaplayer to play an mp3 sound of a button click , whenever i press the button it plays the sound . And it's working fine it's playing the sound but when i click it around 15 times it stops playing the sound i don't know if it's always around 15 or it's a random number of times.
This is the code :

Note : You can ignore the `when` and `if` statments i don't think they have to do anything with this issue.

```
fun play_sound(which_one:Int){
    //Init MediaPlayer..
    val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click)
    if(which_one == 1){
        val is_playing = mediaPlayer?.isPlaying
        when(is_playing){false-> mediaPlayer?.start()}
        }
}
```

And when i use debugging mode that's what i get :(I am using kotlin)

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: invoke failed: wrong state 0, mPlayer(0x7eb285d240)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
V/PlayerBase: baseStop() piid=85911
I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10192, pid: 14428
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is related to a run out of memory or codecs.
The solution is : either you use a ***Mediaplayer pool***  or call ***release()*** method for each instance you finished use it.